# call an class method given an instance in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activemodel

I'm using rails ActiveModel, I defined 2 methods like this:

```
def find_existing_task(task)
  existing_one = Task.find(task.id)
end
def find_existing_person(person)
  existing_one = People.find(person.id)
end
```

But I think I need a more generic method like this:

```
def find_existing(any_active_model_instance_with_id)
  existing_one = ActiveModelClass.find(any_active_model_instance_with_id.id)
end
```

But I don't know how to call the class method given an instance, in above, given task, I can call Task.find without specifing class name "Task"

Any solution? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the following code

```
def find_existing(some_model)
  existing_one = some_model.class.find(some_model.id)
end
```

Comment: thanks for your quick response, and sorry, I didn't make it clear, the find_existing method is defined in a controller, e.g. TasksController, so self.class should be TasksController?

Comment: and what if we define the method neither in Task nor in TasksController?

Comment: @aaron My answer reflects that it may not be called from within a model or controller. What are you trying to do? Are you trying to get an record in your controller for your `show`, `edit`, `update` and `delete` actions?  It would help knowing what you are trying to accomplish, as there might be a better way.

Comment: I want to import an xls into a table called tasks. before the real importing I want to provide a preview table for user, after he confirms, I will read xls again and save them into database. while in the preview, there maybe some records already existed in database,

Comment: so the method is going to find those records out (as well as new records to be added) and notify user they will be updated rather than added. and those records are identified by project_id rather than the default id column. actually the method signature is existing_task = find_existing(task, :distinguish_by => :project_id). also I want to make this function generic for other table import, such as People, existing_person = find_existing(person, :distinguish_by => [:first_name, :last_name])